# How to implement draggable marker in react-native-mapbox-gl?

Tags: react-native, mapbox-gl

I have found that we can render marker either with `PointAnnotation` or `SymbolLayer`.
I couldn't find any documentation related to drag functionality for this. Is there any workaround for this?

Comment: Have you found any solution / workaround for this? I am also looking  for similar functionality.

Comment: @Awadhoot I ended up with select marker and replace by newly added marker.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more? Sorry but I didnt understand what you said.